# How to read URLs (with special characters) with NSXMLParser?

Tags: ios, url, nsxmlparser, encode

I download an XML file that contains several URLs. It works fine, but when I enter a URL in the XML like this:

http://eda-bea.es/pub/record_card_1.php?refpage=%252Fpub%252Fsearch_select.php&quicksearch=adra&page=1&rec=3

the parser stops.

From what I understand is that the URL contains special characters, I have sought and given as a possible solution the following code, where information is encoded to UTF8 before parsing:

```
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:error];
NSData *data = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
[parser setDelegate:self];

[parser parse];
```

It does not work. Stop parsing in this method

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
                                 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
                                qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
                                   attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Something more informative other than "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was using the field

```
<![CDATA[http://eda-bea.es/pub/record_card_1.php?refpage=%252Fpub%252Fsearch_select.php&quicksearch=adra&page=1&rec=3]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Changed Answer**

This link http://eda-bea.es/pub/record_card_1.php?refpage=%252Fpub%252Fsearch_select.php&quicksearch=adra&page=1&rec=3 is not an XML document, it's an HTML document.

The parser will fail on `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="images.php/hispep.css">` because here is no end link tag.

Comment: sorry wrong paste link, this is correct http://eda-bea.es/pub/record_card_1.php?refpage=%252Fpub%252Fsearch_select.php&quicksearch=adra&page=1&rec=3

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were trying to embed that URL into an XML document. I'll give this a second answer.